# How do I give an IAM group access to everything except creating new users?

Tags: amazon-iam

I have a test account where I'd like to give developers access to try out anything they'd like EXCEPT I don't want to give them permissions to add / delete / mess with other users. I tried allowing everything and then denying IAM access but then they couldn't change their own password.  For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

This made it so users got the following error when they tried to login and change their pw:

```
User is not authorized to perform iam:ChangePassword
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a more concise answer you can use wild cards. Not perfectly future proof but those are most of the damaging verbs. :)

Also I found the policy simulator very useful: [IAM policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#roles)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "iam:Add*",
            "iam:Create*",
            "iam:Deactivate*",
            "iam:Delete*",
            "iam:Detach*",
            "iam:Enable*",
            "iam:PassRole",
            "iam:Put*",
            "iam:Remove*",
            "iam:Resync*",
            "iam:Set*",
            "iam:Simulate*",
            "iam:Update*",
            "iam:Put*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below. Using NotAction. This will deny everything for IAM except whatever you mention in NotAction. You can create user using below, but please do note that you will also have to assign policy/roles so add permissions for those under 'NotAction'. Everything else except actions specified in 'NotAction' will be blocked in IAM console. Another part of policy allows everything in console. So just block IAM while allow everything and certain attributes of IAM.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotAction": [
            "iam:CreateUser"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Best regards,
Sanjeev B.

Answer (score 2):

I think I came up with something more generic, using `NotAction`:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "NotAction": ["iam:*"],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["iam:ChangePassword"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of the second statement, perhaps you can just add AWS Managed policies like *IAMUserChangePassword* or *IAMUserSSHKeys* to specific user or group.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an answer that I'm only moderately okay with.  I accomplished this by denying every IAM action except the ability to change password and see the password requirements.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
                "iam:AddUserToGroup",
                "iam:AddClientIDToOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachUserPolicy",
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:CreateAccountAlias",
                "iam:CreateGroup",
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
                "iam:CreateOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:CreatePolicy",
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:CreateSAMLProvider",
                "iam:CreateUser",
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
                "iam:DeleteAccountAlias",
                "iam:DeleteAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteGroup",
                "iam:DeleteGroupPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile",
                "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
                "iam:DeleteOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteSAMLProvider",
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:DeleteServerCertificate",
                "iam:DeleteSigningCertificate",
                "iam:DeleteUser",
                "iam:DeleteUserPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DetachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachUserPolicy",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:GenerateCredentialReport",
                "iam:GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails",
                "iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed",
                "iam:GetAccountAuthorizationDetails",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:GetContextKeysForCustomPolicy",
                "iam:GetContextKeysForPrincipalPolicy",
                "iam:GetCredentialReport",
                "iam:GetGroup",
                "iam:GetGroupPolicy",
                "iam:GetInstanceProfile",
                "iam:GetLoginProfile",
                "iam:GetOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:GetSAMLProvider",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "iam:GetServiceLastAccessedDetails",
                "iam:GetServiceLastAccessedDetailsWithEntities",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:GetUserPolicy",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:ListAccountAliases",
                "iam:ListAttachedGroupPolicies",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListAttachedUserPolicies",
                "iam:ListEntitiesForPolicy",
                "iam:ListGroupPolicies",
                "iam:ListGroups",
                "iam:ListGroupsForUser",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfilesForRole",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListOpenIDConnectProviders",
                "iam:ListPolicies",
                "iam:ListPoliciesGrantingServiceAccess",
                "iam:ListPolicyVersions",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListSAMLProviders",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "iam:ListSigningCertificates",
                "iam:ListUserPolicies",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:PutGroupPolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutUserPolicy",
                "iam:RemoveClientIDFromOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile",
                "iam:RemoveUserFromGroup",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion",
                "iam:SimulateCustomPolicy",
                "iam:SimulatePrincipalPolicy",
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
                "iam:UpdateAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
                "iam:UpdateGroup",
                "iam:UpdateLoginProfile",
                "iam:UpdateOpenIDConnectProviderThumbprint",
                "iam:UpdateSAMLProvider",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UpdateServerCertificate",
                "iam:UpdateSigningCertificate",
                "iam:UpdateUser",
                "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UploadServerCertificate",
                "iam:UploadSigningCertificate"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It works, but I'd love something more concise / future proof.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for Infra admins who don't need access to user/group/policy changes.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AddUserToGroup",
                "iam:AddClientIDToOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachUserPolicy",
                "iam:CreateGroup",
                "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
                "iam:CreateOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:CreatePolicy",
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:CreateSAMLProvider",
                "iam:CreateUser",
                "iam:DeleteAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteGroup",
                "iam:DeleteGroupPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
                "iam:DeleteOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteSAMLProvider",
                "iam:DeleteUser",
                "iam:DeleteUserPolicy",
                "iam:DetachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachUserPolicy",
                "iam:PutGroupPolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutUserPolicy",
                "iam:RemoveClientIDFromOpenIDConnectProvider",
                "iam:RemoveUserFromGroup",
                "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion",
                "iam:UpdateAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
                "iam:UpdateGroup",
                "iam:UpdateLoginProfile",
                "iam:UpdateOpenIDConnectProviderThumbprint",
                "iam:UpdateSAMLProvider",
                "iam:UpdateUser",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```